# Heroku deploy with third part credentials

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a react app using Heroku through Github, but in my app I'm using Youtube Credential, is there any way to config my API credential in order to not expose them in Github

Answer (score 0):

in your root projetc create a file and name it .env and inside it create any variable you want.
ex:
YOUTUB_API = your key

then open your .gitignore file and add this line to it:
.env

now you can use it in your react project like this: process.env.YOUTUB_API

for more informations https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables